# Does clove oil/eugenol interact with nylon type plastics?

Tags: acid-base, polymers, food-chemistry, solvents, plastics

So I am aware that the [eugenol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugenol) in [clove oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_of_clove) readily melts #6 type plastic (polystyrene). Polypropylene has a higher resistance, while HDPE type plastics seem to have the highest resistance.

My main question is whether the clove oil will interact with nylon. Say, the bristles of a toothbrush.

Comment: I would search for plastics/solvent resistence table, looking for aromatic hydrocarbons and their derivates. If eugenol is not used in pure form, it would be strongly affected by the composition of mixture.

Answer (score 2):

Nylon 612, primarily used for [filaments and toothbrushes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nylon#Filaments), is **resistant** to clove oil at 20 °C [1, p. 2034]:

> [image: Screenshot of data from p. 2034 from Chemical Resistance of Thermoplastics]

Nylon 12, used for [coatings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nylon#Powder_Coating), is also **resistant** to clove oil at 20 °C [1, p. 1829]:

> [image: Screenshot of data from p. 1829 from Chemical Resistance of Thermoplastics]

[The tech data on nylon at newmantools.com](https://www.newmantools.com/pipestoppers/NYLON_chem_resistance_nt.pdf) also suggests there is **no effect** of clove oil on nylon in general.

#### References

1. *Chemical Resistance of Thermoplastics*; Woishnis, W. A., Ebnesajjad, S., Eds.; PDL handbook series; William Andrew: Norwich, N.Y, **2012**. ISBN 978-1-4557-7896-6.